# unable to get jsonEncode in magento2

Tags: json, magento, magento2

Magento has its own json encode and decode functions:

```
Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
```

Above code in depreciated in Magento 2. So how to use jsonEncode, what I have to extend to use json Encode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Magento 2 way is pass `Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` using DI functionality (see blow). Don't use `$this->helper()` and `objectManager`. This functionality will be deprecated soon.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
 */
protected $jsonHelper;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper)
{
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
}

/**
 * @param array $dataToEncode
 * @return string
 */
public function encodeSomething(array $dataToEncode)
{
    $encodedData = $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($dataToEncode);

    return $encodedData;
}
```

Comment: i have referenced the magento 2 developers guide by branko ajzele ,page number 171, there its clearly given using object manager.i think objcetmanager is the best

Comment: I'm assuming that this guide is not correct. Please check an answer from Magento architecture Anton Kril: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10517/instantiating-helpers-in-magento-2

Comment: Using that helper is deprecated already. Please use `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` instead - there is the `serialize` and `unserialize` method.

Comment: \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data is deprecated @ 101.0.0, Magento will remove this class in future 

use \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json

Answer (score 8):

Using `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` is deprecated from Magento 2.2 onward, 
for versions >= 2.2, you can use `SerializerInterface`

From the Magento 2 devdocs:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/framework/serializer.html#json-default

```
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

/**
 * @var SerializerInterface
 */
private $serializer;


public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer) {
  $this->serializer = $serializer;
}


public function encodeSomething($data) {
    return $this->serializer->serialize($data)
}

public function decodeSomething($data) {
    return $this->serializer->unserialize($data)
}
```

That ends up calling a class which runs json_encode() and json_decode() https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

So, if you're running on 2.1 or lower, you could use native PHP functions `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` and get the same result, or use the deprecated `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($array);
```

or

```
$jsonHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data');
echo $jsonHelper->jsonEncode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Magento 2.4.1</sup>

Inject class in constructor() `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json`

```
...
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json as JsonSerialize;

/**
* @var JsonSerialize
*/
private $jsonSerialize;

/**
* Constructor
* @param JsonSerialize $jsonSerialize
*/
public function __construct(
    ...
    JsonSerialize $jsonSerialize
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->jsonSerialize = $jsonSerialize;
    ...
}
```

Then you can use :

```
$this->jsonSerialize->serialize($data_here) // json_encode
$this->jsonSerialize->unserialize($data_here) // json_decode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following static method:

```
\Magento\Framework\Serialize\JsonConverter::convert($data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder $jsonDecoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Encoder $jsonEncoder,
    \CP\Coreoverride\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
)
{
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->_jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
    $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    $this->_serializer = $serializer;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function decodeData($data) {
  $dataArray = $this->_jsonDecoder->decode($data);
  $result = $this->_serializer->unserialize($dataArray);
  return $result;
}

public function encodeData($data) {
    $dataArray = $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($data);
    $result = $this->_serializer->unserialize($dataArray);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data;        

 protected $jsonHelper;

 public function __construct(
          Data $jsonHelper
        ) {

         $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;

        }

 protected function jsonResponse()
    {
     $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to encode the given array to JSON, the direct PHP function should be used i.e. `json_encode`

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php