# Unable to get jsonDecode in magento 2

Tags: json, magento2

Magento 1.x has its own JSON decode functions:

```
Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($array);
```

So how to use JSON Decode in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Magento2 (2.2.3) the `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` class is deprecated and may no longer be used in future versions. Therefore it is highly recommended to use the `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` class instead to decode a json string or encode an array to a json string.

```
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
     */
    protected $_jsonSerializer;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_jsonSerializer = $jsonSerializer;
        ...
    }

    public function decodeJsonString($jsonString)
    {
        return $this->_jsonSerializer->unserialize($jsonString);
    }

    public function encodeArray($array)
    {
        return $this->_jsonSerializer->serialize($array);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code with magento 2 for json decode

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$jsonManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder');
return $jsonManager->decode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [**This Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244822/5635098)

**Method 1:**

```
echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonDecode($array);
```

Or

```
$jsonHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data');
echo $jsonHelper->jsonDecode($array);
```

**Method 2:**

```
 /**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper)
{
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
}

/**
 * @param array $dataToDecode
 * @return string
 */
public function decodeSomething(array $dataToDecode)
{
    $decodedData= $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($dataToDecode);

    return $decodedData;
}
```